# XQuery Replace 'ü' to 'u' for Turkish characters

Tags: xquery, microstrategy

i've function for dynamic parameter. Im using MicroStrategy tool for this.

let $uri := replace('http://url/suggest?searchTerm=DYNAMIC PROMPT','\s+','%20')

i want to replace 'ü' to 'u' for in this function. I already use ('\s+','%20') for space character.

Comment: If you want to use a user-defined string in a URL, replacing problematic characters one at a time will always be incomplete. New symbols are added to Unicode and people can add Emoji and lots of other things into text fields now. The proper solution is the function [`fn:encode-for-uri($str)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-encode-for-uri), which can deal with all possible strings. `encode-for-uri('Istanbul to Karabük')` for example will return the encoded string `'Istanbul%20to%20Karab%C3%BCk'`.

Comment: And it works: https://maps.google.com?q=Istanbul%20to%20Karab%C3%BCk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple `replace` functions can be nested:

```
let $string := 'http://url/suggest?searchTerm=DüNAMIC PROMPT'
let $uri := replace(replace($string, '\s+','%20'), 'ü', 'u')
return $uri
```

For replacing single characters, you can also use the `translate` function:

```
let $string := 'http://url/suggest?searchTerm=DüNAMIC PROMPT'
let $uri := translate($string, ' üÜöÖäÄ','+uUoOaA')
return $uri
```

Answer (score 0):

Can i use "let $uri := replace(replace($string, '\s+','%20'), 'ü', 'u')" this for multiple characters.
For example: let $uri := replace(replace($string, '\s+','%20'),'üÜöÖäÄ','+uUoOaA')

Because i need two replace case.

Microstrategy doesn't support this case. For example i gave 'Müşteri' keyword that gaves me different answers :(

Comment: With fn:translate, multiple single search and replace characters can be supplied; with fn:replace, a single regex pattern can be specified for searching and replacing strings. See e.g. http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0008.html#c0020 to learn more about these functions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Leo's suggestion that `fn:encode-for-uri()` is the way to go for the stated use case - i.e., for handling spaces, special characters, and diacritics when constructing a URL.

But if you are interested in stripping diacritics from a string, here's how you'd do that:

```
xquery version "3.1";

"Müşteri" 
=> normalize-unicode("NFD") 
=> replace("\p{IsCombiningDiacriticalMarks}", "")
```

This returns `Musteri`.

For reference, this is based on the Gist I posted at https://gist.github.com/joewiz/af04074c28e0ae2a1b92.